# Community wiki answer changes to normal on migration?

Tags: bug, migration, community-wiki

My recent [community wiki answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/400297/timeline), on migration to ELL, [changed to normal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/136642/29183).

Is this normal?

It's possible that some people on ELL will think that I'm copypasting others' comments for rep.

Comment: Probably relevant: [MSE on migrating CW answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158174/weird-behavior-of-community-wiki-answers-after-migration) Related as well: [MSE on migrating CW questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84873/migrated-cw-question-no-longer-community-wiki).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks, but looks like I'd already visited those pages a while ago. My votes are already there. But those are relevant only to a time when posts were automatically converted to CW.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I now think it's better suited to MSE. Should it be migrated there? You please decide and take action.

Comment: It's OK here at the moment. The point of the MSE/answers link was that CW migration was heavily reworked so that the original author didn't get lost in translation. I suspect that means that the original author is deliberately restored. I'll make this a bug report here, I think, so staff get to see it easily, and they may confirm what's going on. It should be open to you to make the migrated answer into CW yourself, of course.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Okay, you know better. If it's best here, let it stay. And I'll keep the "normalized" migrated answer as it is, for reference.